# Switched to Compiz for OpenGL on Xubuntu 12.04, now laptop screen doesn't turn on after a suspend

Tags: 12.04, compiz, laptop, suspend, xfce

I recently added the CompizConfig settings manager to resolve screen tearing while watching full screen video (it worked! no more tearing!) but now every time I close the laptop screen and the system suspends, then open the laptop again, the screen stays black and does not turn on.

I know that the system is turned on because I can hear the fan running and if I press Ctrl+Alt+F2, type my login information, then `sudo reboot` the system will follow through and reboot. Otherwise I have to do a hard reset to resolve the blank screen.

The screen would turn on before installing Compiz which is why I think it's the culprit (I was using the proprietary Catalyst driver) . Is there something I can do to force the screen to turn on after/during a suspend-resume?